# Variable without var

Tags: javascript, scope

Regarding,
**Local variables** ...

```
function foo(){var x = 1;  ...}
```

...and **Global variables**, ...
(global, example 1)

```
function foo(){x = 1;  ...}
```

(global, example 2)

```
var x=1; function foo(){...}
```

...the only (simple) combination left is:

```
x=1; function foo{...}
```

... which I tested and noticed it also creates a global variable (like example 2), but is there any practical reason for this last example? 
*Note: I generally like to follow conventions and write readable code and stay away from 'weirdness'.*

Comment: Practical reason for _what_ ?

Comment: '...for the final example'. I will edit the question.

Comment: It's the same as the second example.. a global variable. you want to be able to generate a global variable in the global context, right?

Comment: yi_H, I'm just studying and making note of all possible combinations.  You said, "It's the same as the second example." Yes, I thought so, but I think it is unconventional; it is best to stick with standard conventions, so I will not mention this option it in my personal notes... unless someone convinces me there is a good reason for it.

Comment: there is rarely good reason for a global variable so your argument is valid for the second case too. Is still don't understand why you trying to differentiate between these two

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because JavaScript is a dynamic language. It allows you to use a variable without declaring it. You should always declare variables to eliminate confusion as you discussed. JSLint/JSHint will complain if you don't.

<strike>Your "(global, example 1)" is wrong. that does not create a global variable.</strike>

```
function foo() { x = 1; }
function bar() { 
   alert(x);
}
foo();
bar();
```

**edit** i was wrong. http://jsfiddle.net/awuzA/

Comment: x is not global?: function foo(){x = 1;  ...}

Comment: Is this person wrong? "If a variable is initialized inside a function without var, it will have a global scope." source: http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tutorials/javascript/global_local_variables_scope_javascript.php3

Comment: Daniel, I admire a person who can say that.  Thanks for helping sort this out.